# Как поменять текст описания сайта на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, seo, поисковые-системы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поменять описание сайта, который сделан на вордпрессе?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?vid=0-1316808684509-1512569497337 читай внимательно. Первый абзац до полного понимания ситуации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `header.php` изменить содержимое тега  `< meta name="description" content="Содержимое мета-тега">` на нужное вам.

Либо в админке: Настройки - Общие - Краткое описание

Comment: А что делать если я добавил https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/12/6/7813fae677bb2672678540e29394a114-full.png но не чего не изменилось при поиске сайта, и в админке тоже поменял

Comment: В один момент в Гугл ничего не изменится. Нужно ждать пока поисковый робот снова просканирует сайт.

Comment: хорошо спасибо, буду ждать)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно установить СЕО плагин.